Rav Chaim Volozhin - being moser nefesh for teshuva
In the Shabbos Shuva drasha printed at the end of Ruach Chaim, Rav Chaim Volozhiner, says one must be moser nefesh for teshuva.
His source is from the posuk:

וְשַׁבְתָּ עַד ה’ אֱלֹקיךָ כו’ בְּכָל לְבָבְךָ וּבְכָל נַפְשֶׁךָ
And you return to your G-d...with all your heart and with your soul
(Devarim 30:2)

His proof to this is from the Gemara in Avodah Zara 17a which tells us about Rebbi Elazar ben Durdaya who was a big baal aveirah to the point that he wasn’t able to do teshuva. Once he realized this, he said, “אין הדבר תלוי אלא בי” — “It all depends on me — the responsibility is totally mine!” He then put his head between his knees and cried until he died after which a bas kol (heavenly voice) emerged from shamayim and declared, “Rebbi Elazer ben Durdaya is worthy of Olam Habbah.”
The question is that we only find one has to be moser nefesh for the big three; idol worship, immorality and murder (Mishneh Torah - Yesodei HaTorah 5:2), so how can Rav Chaim Volozhiner now add in teshuva as well?

I don't understand Rav Chaim Volozhiner's statement from a different direction: The story from the Gemara demonstrates that one can be moser nefesh for teshuva (i.e. it is a possibility). Where does he get (from that story) that one must be moser nefesh for teshuva (i.e. that it is an obligation)?

If Rabbi Elazar ben Durdaya was not obligated to do what he did, then it would be simple suicide.  If so, he would have been condemned, not praised.
Also, בכל נפשך in the posuk presumably means the same thing that it means in קריאת שמע; namely, אפילו הוא נוטל את נפשך/

@YehoshuaKahan "If Rabbi Elazar ben Durdaya was not obligated to do what he did, then it would be simple suicide. If so, he would have been condemned, not praised." That would be true, only if his intent was to die. By your logic, as teshuva was otherwise impossible, why didn't he shorten the process, and make it more definite, by shoving a knife through his heart, or slitting his veins? Sitting and crying suggests he didn't know what to do, nor that dying would bring him any good.

At some point, he must have felt his physical strength giving out, his vision fading and other symptoms.  At that point, he could have stopped, said to himself "I did all I could," and had lunch.  Instead, he kept going, even though he knew that he was endangering and ultimately sacrificing his life.   As for why he didn't stab himself or slit his veins, he was not trying to die, he was trying to do Teshuva.  But the Teshuva that he needed to do could only be accomplished by an effort so supreme that it actually cost him his life.  (continued in next) @TamirEvan

(continued from previous)  It would be like a man who wants a car, and needs to spend $40000 to buy it.  Would anyone dream that he might spare himself the bother of buying the car, and just set $40000 on fire instead?  So to, if Rabbi Elazar ben Durdaya had just stabbed himself, he would have lost the main thing--Teshuva!   @TamirEvan

There's another example of this, in regards to learning Torah.  In Brachos 61b, we find:

The Rabbis taught:  One time the Evil Empire decreed that the Jews may
not learn Torah.  Papus ben Yehudah found Rabbi Akiva teaching Torah
to large crowds.  He asked him:  Akiva, aren't you frightened of the
Empire?  Rabbi Akiva responded: I will provide you a parable.  One
time there was a fox walking alongside a river, and he saw fishes
swimming from one spot to another.  He asked them:  What are you
fleeing?  And they answered:  We flee the fishermen and their nets!
Responded the fox:  Do you want to come up on the dry land and live
together with me, as my ancestors and your ancestors once dwelt
together?  Answered the fishes:  Are you the one that I call the
cleverest of all beasts?  You are not clever--you are a fool!  In the
place where we can live we are afraid, in the place where we must die
how much more so!  The same is true of us.  We sit and learn Torah,
about which the verse says 'For it is your life and the length of your
days' and we are afraid--if we would stop learning Torah, how much
more so!  They said:  Not much later, they arrested Rabbi Akiva and
imprisoned him, and they arrested Papus ben Yehuda and imprisoned him
together with Rabbi Akiva.  He said:  Papus, who brought you here?  He
responded:  How fortunate are you, Akiva, that you wre seized for the
sake of Torah--and woe to Papup, who was seized for the sake of
worthless things.  When they took Rabbi Akiva out to execute him, it
was the time of Krias Shema, and they were scraping off his flesh with
iron scrapers, and he recited Krias Shema and accepted Hashem's
Kingdom.  His disciples asked him:  Our teacher, how can you be so
focused?  He responded:  All my life I was worried about the verse of
"And with all your soul," meaning "even if He takes your soul."  Now
that it has come to me, shall I not fulfill it?  He extended his
recitation of the word "One," and his soul left him as he pronounced
it.  A Heavenly Voice declared:  You are fortunate, Rabbi Akiva, and
you are invited to the life of the World to Come!

How was Rabbi Akiva allowed to give up his life for the sake of Torah?  Notice that he does not argue that it is a time of shemad, and then one must give up his life for any mitzvah; he provides a lengthy parable to emphasize the uniqueness of Torah.
I would suggest to you that when it comes to a one-off sin, even the most terrible, the sinner can potentially rebuild his connection to Hashem afterwards.   Even if he committed idolatry, arayos, or murder, he can come close again afterwards.  Therefore, with regards to those issurim, I could well have thought that one should not give his life rather than transgress.
However, if we stop learning Torah, there is no possibility of having any connection to Hashem.  And if we cannot do Teshuva, there is no possibility of any connection to Hashem.  Therefore, when it comes to these mitzvos, it is obvious that one must pay any price in order to fulfill them, up to an including giving his life.
Brachos 61b
